# How can an answer posted by a 3.5k rep user get used as an Audit in the "First-Post" review queue?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review-audits

I know that the automatic system can make some weird choices on audits.. But taking a post made by a 3.5k rep poster as a **First-Post** audit is a little bit off the track..

> This screenshot was taken before the audit was completed (we can still see the buttons here ↓)
>   [image: Audit Screenshot]

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5496963

It reads :

> This is the **first answer** posted by a **new user**. Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post.

This is **obviously** not a **first answer** nor a **new user**.

How can this even happen?

Or, if it is normal, shouldn't this usercard be "anonymized"? (Is this a bug?)

Added the bug report [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237773/audit-first-post-review-not-anonymized-3-5k-user-answer-used-as-the-audit)

Comment: Ok, but that's something you know after you've visited the poster's profile. Meaning you were paying attention. But I agree that it would be better if FP audits displayed low-rep users.

Comment: Maybe an account merge?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Are you sure that "First-Answers" (even after multiple questions asked) count as "First-Posts"? I didn't look at the user profile until when I posted this question, wondering **how** a 3.5k rep user can have his post in a FP audit. Also, not a lot of attention is required to notice the gold badge and the 3.5k rep the user has. Which makes the audit quite obvious. Isn't an audit suppose to be similar to real cases?

Comment: If I remember correctly, audits replace the username / rep with an unregistered user

Comment: @Joe Have you looked at the screenshot I took?

Comment: @Sifu yes, so it is either a bug in the audit system failing to anonymize the data, or something else going on like an account merge.

Comment: FWIW I've always disliked the way this type of audit was supposed to work; and IIRC some of the first few I got because the quality of the answer had me suspecting plagiarism; which I thought I'd confirmed when I saw the same text by a long term/high rep user after visiting the question outside the audit.

Comment: @DanNeely That was my first failed audit as well. Tried to flag for moderator attention as it was an exact copy of an existing answer. If possible, the usercard could also be changed when viewing all the answers to the question to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have audited our audit code and it should be faking up a low rep user and showing you the real rep after completion of the audit.

Comment: Cross-site dupe with a bounty: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237773/audit-first-post-review-not-anonymized-3-5k-user-answer-used-as-the-audit.

Comment: I have audited our audit code... :)

Answer (score 8):

[It happens.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5001309)

That said, the usercard should have been anonymized when you were completing the audit: that is, you should have seen a blank avatar and/or a low total reputation in the area that denotes the post's author. If it showed the user's real reputation and badges, it is a bug that should be reported.

The *real* usercard should appear **after** you complete the audit.

From the [review page](//stackoverflow.com/review) (emphasis mine):

> ### First Posts
>
> Review first posts from **new users**

First questions/answers from **new users** (not experienced ones) are ushered into the queue upon posting, but audits sometimes dip into the history of experienced users, so it all depends on the particular audit.

If you see a high-quality question/answer from a low-rep user, you should be suspicious, because it is probably an audit. In this case, it was a low-quality answer from an experienced user, but it wouldn't be out of place in the normal flow of the queue, since many first posts from new users look like that (link-only, odd exclamatory statements, etc.).

Comment: I added the "Bug" tag to my question. As this was obviously not intended.

Comment: Look at my screenshot. The buttons are still showing, this means that this was indeed **before** I completed the audit.

Comment: @Sifu It's interesting that it showed up *before* you completed the audit. If I remember correctly, it should be anonymized.

Comment: @Sifu [Looks like a bug](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2293162#2293162).